# Cannot create a project using yarn in nest

Tags: nestjs, yarnpkg

After executing the command "nest new backed", I selected yarn to create the project. The version of yarn is 4.1.0. I tried version 3, but it didn't make any difference. I don't know how to solve this problem.

error

```
error Failed to execute command: yarn install --silent
```

```
Usage Error: The nearest package directory (/Users/dev/backed) doesn't seem to be part of the project declared in /Users/dev.

- If /Users/dev isn't intended to be a project, remove any yarn.lock and/or package.json file there.
- If /Users/dev is intended to be a project, it might be that you forgot to list act-backed in its workspace configuration.
- Finally, if /Users/dev is fine and you intend act-backed to be treated as a completely separate project (not even a workspace), create an empty yarn.lock file in it.

$ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--refresh-lockfile] [--check-cache] [--check-resolutions] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
```

Comment: show any logs, please

Comment: show please: `yarn -v`

Comment: yarn version is 4.1.0.

Comment: Moreover, node_module is not even made. But if I install it with npm, no error occurs.Moreover, node_module is not even made. But if I install it with npm, no error occurs.

Comment: try yarn v1.22.19 it works fine